# How do I solve a matrix equation of non commuting variables in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I would like to solve the system A*B=I for the elements of B in terms of the elements of A.

A and B are square, the elements of A and B don't commute (i.e. A[1,1]*B[1,1]=/=B[1,1]*A[1,1]), and A and B are of size nxn.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
In[16]:= n = 2;

In[34]:= Reduce[Flatten[Table[
   Sum[A[i, j] ** B[j, k], {j, 1, n}] == KroneckerDelta[i, k], {i, 1, 
    n}, {k, 1, n}]], {B[1, 1]}]

During evaluation of In[34]:= Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Out[34]= Reduce[{A[1, 1] ** B[1, 1] + A[1, 2] ** B[2, 1] == 1, 
  A[1, 1] ** B[1, 2] + A[1, 2] ** B[2, 2] == 0, 
  A[2, 1] ** B[1, 1] + A[2, 2] ** B[2, 1] == 0, 
  A[2, 1] ** B[1, 2] + A[2, 2] ** B[2, 2] == 1}, {B[1, 1]}]
```

Could you please let me know how I can fix this code to make it work? If n=2, the solution should be one of the either one of last 2 equations here:

http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf

Comment: Seems to be related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-mathematica-do-symbolic-linear-algebra

Comment: This https://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ Mathematica package looks like it might provide you with the tools to do exactly what you want.